# set of non-decreasing functions from Q->{0,1}

Tags: real-analysis

Given the set $ A= \{f:ℤ→\{0,1\}| if x \geq y, f(x)\geq f(y)\}$ - set of non-decreasing functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\{0,1\}$. I want to prove that A is countable, hence I'm trying to build a bijection $\mathbb{N}→A$,but I don't know how to proceed. I suppose I need to prove that the point where the function changes its value has countable number of choices. Can anybody help me? And the other question I want to ask is: "Will A still be countable if we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\Bbb Z$, most of the nondecreasing functions start with an infinite run of $0$s, then step up to $1$ at some point and have $1$s from there on out.  A natural bijection with the integers is the point they step up.  There are two more functions you need to worry about, the one that is all $0$s and the one that is all $1$s.  You just need to biject the integers plus two points with $N$ and you are done.

No, $A$ will not be countable if you replace $\Bbb Z$ with $\Bbb Q$.  Your functions are then Dedekind cuts and you get one for each real.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are sequences with terms zero or one such that if you have a single one then you have all ones after that.

So the location where the first one appears determines your function uniquely.

Thus you have a one to one function $G:Z\to A$ where $G(k)$ is the sequence which has all zeros up to $k-1$ term and all ones starting at the $k^{th}$ term.

Similar argument  does not work for $Q$ instead of $Z$ because you can not  make a sequence of all rational numbers where order is preserved.

Comment: You can't really talk about the $k^{th}$ term of a function on the integers, but you can just change to $G(k)$ is all zeros up to $k-1$.  This misses the all $0$ and all $1$ functions.

Comment: @RossMillikan I agree with all 0, but isn't G(1) - the sequence of all 1?

Comment: No, $\Bbb Z$ is the integers, so $G(1)$ is the function that is $0$ for any argument less than $1$, the negatives and $0$, and is $1$ for any argument $\ge 1$. $G(-5)$ is the function that is $0$ for any argument $\le -6$ and $1$ for any argument $\ge -5$

Comment: I didn't get the part about rational numbers, can you explain again the case with Q by giving an example for Q where order is not preserved?

Comment: What l mean is that we can not list rationals from smallest to largest so we do not have the concept of next rational.